# Accessibility of functions inside custom pallet

Tags: pallet, runtime, frame, call, coupling

I have two custom pallets `pallet1` and `pallet2`. In `pallet1` I have a bunch of calls with assigned weights declared under pallet call macro like this

```rs
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  dispatchables
}
```

In `pallet1` I also have a bunch of public helper functions outside of call macro, they are at the bottom of my pallets code

```rs
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  pub fn do_things(args) -> DispatchResult {}
}
```

Now `pallet2` can call these helper functions from `pallet1` through coupling mechanism

```rs
pallet1::Pallet::<T>::do_things(args)
```

Is there a way to call these functions externally/directly by submitting some extrinsic or other means like `state_call` rpc or something
or the only way to invoke them outside pallet1 is hardcoding calls to these functions in other custom pallets

Comment: Did you mean using pallet-a to call pallet-b's calls?

Comment: You mention `pallet-1` twice. Please correct that.

Comment: I mean if I expose do_things() for other pallets to use, does it make do_things() callable(dispatchable) anyhow? I can hardcode a call `pallet1::Pallet::<T>::do_things(args)` inside new palletX when I'm writing it. Are there other ways to dispatch do_things()?

Comment: Not sure I understand propertly what are you trying to do, if you want to make do_things callable externaly why don't turn into an extrinsic?

Comment: @AlexBean Just started learning substrate. One of the tutorials says "using internal functions you don't need to do any kind of authorization for the operations performed because the internal functions are only accessible to you as the runtime developer."
However this tutorial deals with one pallet only and does not consider coupling. Tryna understand if I need access control in do_things(). I found another question that contradicts tutorial info but cant comment on it because of low rep here https://stackoverflow.com/q/70974061/21294431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question of "Do I need to worry about access control for `do_things` if other pallets can call it?", the answer is no, you don't need to worry. Even though it is accessible from other pallets, only the one deploying an appchain or parachain can choose which pallets exist and what they do. As long as you make sure that there are appropriate access control checks whenever an extrinsic causes `pallet2` to call `pallet1::do_things`, you'll be fine.

For these public non-extrinsic functions to be executed, they need to be a side effect of someone submitting an extrinsic to one of the pallets running in your chain.

In general, for functions that change things to be accessible externally, they need to be caused by an extrinsic. So if this function changes any state, it can't meaningfully be called via RPC alone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you are looking for, but you could have a higher abstraction for your `do_things`, a `DoThings` trait. Your `pallet2` via `Config` will depend from a higher abstraction `DoThings`.

Example:
`Preimage` type of `Scheduler`'s pallet config, it is defined as a type requiring `QueryPreimage` and `StorePreimage` traits, and one of the implementations of these traits is `Preimage` pallet.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e2c5a564e5a83e1f63d47a4fa300567901f00afc/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L230